# Trying to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server where the difference is the date or batch number

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID_NUMBER,                                                                    
    T1.INCEPTION_DATE,
    T1.OCCURRENCE,
    T1.TRANSACTION_DATE,
    T1.FILE_LOAD_DATE,
    T1.BATCH_NUM
FROM 
    mastertable T1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ID_NUMBER, INCEPTION_DATE, OCCURRENCE, 
         COUNT(*) AS DUPL_COUNT
     FROM 
         mastertable
     WHERE 
         SOURCE_SYSTEM ='LEGACY'
     GROUP BY 
         ID_NUMBER, INCEPTION_DATE, OCCURRENCE
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON T2.ID_NUMBER = T1.ID_NUMBER 
                          AND T2.INCEPTION_DATE = T1.INCEPTION_DATE 
                          AND T2.OCCURRENCE= T1.OCCURRENCE
ORDER BY 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Which is returning the following results

| ID_NUMBER | INCEPTION_DATE | OCCURRENCE | TRANSACTION_DATE | FILE_LOAD_DATE | BATCH_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112897732 | 2008-09-15 | 4 | 2008-07-03 | 2008-07-07 17:57:19 | 06341 |
| 112897732 | 2008-09-15 | 4 | 2008-07-13 | 2008-07-18 03:35:55 | 06753 |
| 828194721 | 2008-11-11 | 1 | 2008-09-06 | 2008-09-17 02:50:44 | 97334 |
| 828194721 | 2008-11-11 | 1 | 2008-09-23 | 2008-09-24 02:55:27 | 98331 |
| 456457422 | 2008-09-28 | 1 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-07-13 08:08:39 | 00734 |
| 456457422 | 2008-09-28 | 1 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-07-18 13:35:55 | 00991 |
| 999272910 | 2008-05-07 | 3 | 2008-05-03 | 2008-10-13 08:08:38 | 11432 |
| 999272910 | 2008-05-07 | 3 | 2008-05-28 | 2008-10-18 03:35:55 | 13342 |
| 875328642 | 2008-03-01 | 3 | 2008-04-28 | 2008-01-23 08:08:38 | 74542 |
| 875328642 | 2008-03-01 | 3 | 2008-04-30 | 2008-01-25 12:55:11 | 77536 |
| 011028734 | 2008-07-12 | 2 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-08-07 11:57:03 | 23422 |
| 011028734 | 2008-07-12 | 2 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-08-11 17:23:29 | 25748 |
| 018264981 | 2008-07-09 | 0 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-12-07 02:18:12 | 00432 |
| 018264981 | 2008-07-09 | 0 | 2008-12-03 | 2008-12-11 17:44:19 | 00773 |

The earlier `FILE_LOAD_DATE` of each `ID_NUMBER` or lesser `BATCH_NUM` is the record I want to keep.

Is there a way to write a query that will delete the other records, perhaps using a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER()`?

I am hoping for something that is DRY in case this issue happens again. Thanks!

(Also if it isn't too much trouble please explain how the solution works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a deletable CTE here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NUMBER, INCEPTION_DATE, OCCURRENCE
                                 ORDER BY FILE_LOAD_DATE, BATCH_NUM) rn
    FROM mastertable
    WHERE SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'LEGACY'
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

The logic is to assign a row number to each group of records having the same values for `ID_NUMBER`, `INCEPTION_DATE`, and `OCCURRENCE`.  The first row number value of 1 will be assigned to the record having the *earliest* `FILE_LOAD_DATE`.  In cases of two or more records tied for the earliest `FILE_LOAD_DATE`, the tie breaker will be determined by the earliest `BATCH_NUM`.

The delete statement removes all records *except* for this earliest record.